# drive api -- get email based on public file link

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

say I have a file link in the format of something like

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1o9rhnAr2GIilfjxPm4Wdl1BlaVP4Gsj1
```

Is it at all possible to get the email address of the one who uploaded this file, since the link is public? I haven't been able to find anything like this in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [File.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) request

will return all the information about the file including the users email.  I have altered it slightly but anyone running this request is going to get your email you might want to scramble that file id :)

All you need is an API key to be able to get information about a public file.

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1o9rhnAr2GIilfjxPm4Wdl1BlaVP4Gsj1?fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \    
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

## response

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1o9rhnAr2GIilfjxPm4Wdl1BlaVP4Gsj1",
 "name": "pokemon_terrain.jpg",
 "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ],
 "version": "5",
 "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1o9rhnAr2GIilfjxPm4Wdl1BlaVP4Gsj1&export=download",
 "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o9rhnAr2GIilfjxPm4Wdl1BlaVP4Gsj1/view?usp=drivesdk",
 "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/jpeg",
 "hasThumbnail": true,
 "thumbnailLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1ZX-DvVSs70fPta2IAsg8tpYbkRDFeU0p-MVIdZPKY2PAGCGLqCAnXPl3MNMcafYNVfmAe2qips=s220",
 "thumbnailVersion": "1",
 "viewedByMe": false,
 "createdTime": "2019-09-16T09:43:40.107Z",
 "modifiedTime": "2020-02-13T14:12:57.036Z",
 "modifiedByMe": false,
 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "p v",
   "photoLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjNKXej3SKi_Rc7VwlULYtsnN_A4uYJsxwoc_FR=s64",
   "me": false,
   "permissionId": "15907603398143100492",
   "emailAddress": "vou.pandev@gmail.com"
  }
 ],
 "lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "p v",
  "photoLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjNKXej3SKi_Rc7VwlULYtsnN_A4uYJsxwoc_FR=s64",
  "me": false,
  "permissionId": "15907603398143100492",
  "emailAddress": "vourtspandev@gmail.com"
 },
 "shared": true,
 "ownedByMe": false,
 "capabilities": {
  "canAddChildren": false,
  "canAddMyDriveParent": false,
  "canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
  "canChangeViewersCanCopyContent": false,
  "canComment": false,
  "canCopy": false,
  "canDelete": false,
  "canDownload": true,
  "canEdit": false,
  "canListChildren": false,
  "canModifyContent": false,
  "canMoveChildrenWithinDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemOutOfDrive": false,
  "canMoveItemWithinDrive": false,
  "canReadRevisions": false,
  "canRemoveChildren": false,
  "canRemoveMyDriveParent": true,
  "canRename": false,
  "canShare": false,
  "canTrash": false,
  "canUntrash": false
 },
 "viewersCanCopyContent": true,
 "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "originalFilename": "pokemon_terrain.jpg",
 "fullFileExtension": "jpg",
 "fileExtension": "jpg",
 "md5Checksum": "e7bb0cb361585f3845bd2a11e769c70b",
 "size": "326467",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
 "headRevisionId": "0BwYB7bTd8hGMd3A4WERUVHpuODNDdmM2MlZlNUNGQk9rc2hNPQ",
 "imageMediaMetadata": {
  "width": 460,
  "height": 460,
  "rotation": 0
 }
}
```

Comment: good thing the file ID isn't my own file :) thanks tho

Comment: although r u sure its not the v2 api?